# How can I change a div's height dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<div id="right_side_bar">` with css:

```
#right_side_bar{
margin-top:38px;
    width:272px;
    margin-left:722px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

I saw similar questions on stack but I can't figure out how to make the right_side_bar change its height so that its always 100% of the window.  I want it fixed so that it doesn't scroll with the rest of the page. But exactly the way Gawker.com does it where the div itself is scrollable.

Comment: I think you have two different approaches confused; static positioning and parent-height-relative calculated height.

Comment: You should get [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) or use "inspect element" in chrome to look at the style of the bar, it's all right there for the taking

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

```
#right_side_bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 38px;
    bottom: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 272px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't change make the div scrollable, basically the div is just cut-off, any idea?

Comment: I thought that's what the `overflow-y: scroll` did. Can you show a screenshot of what's going wrong?

Comment: Here are two screenshots.  The first shows the div and then the second shows it after a window resize, neither allows for a scroll so the full div isn't accessible.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/46kht.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/AcOqL.png

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the problem in this case, but I recall that some browsers have, historically, had problems if `overflow-y` was set without setting `overflow-x` (and vice-versa).

Comment: The way it is done on Gawker is the div's height automatically changes, so as you resize you see the style height tag change dynamically.  I don't think its a position:fixed fix